# Python - dataframe conditional index value selection

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe similar to the below:

```
                       close_price  short_lower_band  long_lower_band
Equity(8554)               180.530        184.235603       183.964306
Equity(2174)               166.830        157.450404       157.160282
Equity(23921)              124.670        127.243468       126.072039
Equity(26807)              117.910        108.761587       107.190081
Equity(42950)              108.070         97.491851        96.868036
Equity(4151)                97.380         98.954371        98.335786
```

I want to generate a list of index values where 'close price' is less than 'short_lower_band' and less than 'long_lower_band'. So from the sample dataframe above we would get:

```
long_secs = [Equity(8554), Equity(23921), Equity(4151)]
```

Any help in figuring out how to do this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
In [334]: df
Out[334]:
               close_price  short_lower_band  long_lower_band
Equity(8554)        180.53        184.235603       183.964306
Equity(2174)        166.83        157.450404       157.160282
Equity(23921)       124.67        127.243468       126.072039
Equity(26807)       117.91        108.761587       107.190081
Equity(42950)       108.07         97.491851        96.868036
Equity(4151)         97.38         98.954371        98.335786

In [335]:

In [335]: df[(df.close_price < df.short_lower_band) & \
   .....:    (df.close_price < df.long_lower_band)].index.values
Out[335]: array(['Equity(8554)', 'Equity(23921)', 'Equity(4151)'], dtype=object)
```

or if you need a plain list instead of numpy array:

```
In [336]: df[(df.close_price < df.short_lower_band) & \
   .....:    (df.close_price < df.long_lower_band)].index.tolist()
Out[336]: ['Equity(8554)', 'Equity(23921)', 'Equity(4151)']
```